# How to add statements to an existing method definition in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I noticed for the class definition, if I open up the `class MyClass`, and add something in between without overwrite I still got the original method which defined earlier. The new statements added augment the existing one.

But as to the method definition, I still want the same behavior as the class definition, but it seems when I open up the `def my_method`, the exiting statements within the `def` and `end` is overwritten, I need to rewrite that again.

So is there any way to make the method definition behave the same as definition, something like `super`, but not necessarily is the sub-class?

Comment: you can store the old method in a variable

Comment: This is largely a duplicate of [When monkey patching a method, can you call the overridden method from the new implementation](http://StackOverflow.Com/questions/4470108/when-monkey-patching-a-method-can-you-call-the-overridden-method-from-the-new-im/4471202/#4471202).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suppose you are looking for [alias_method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M000447):

```
class A
  alias_method :old_func, :func

  def func
    old_func # similar to calling 'super'
    # do other stuff
  end
end
```